# Apache hosting server SMTP configuration

Tags: email, smtp, hosting

When I hosted my website with GoDaddy I had a default email account that I could send emails to *anythign@mydomainname.com and it would be in the default account inbox. Bluehost is telling me they have no such feature. Is there something I can do?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about email configuration.

Comment: programers use smtp for all kinds of reasons. Chron jobs are an essential part of any web applications. The question was at least unique if nothing else. uhg. smh

Comment: You can demonstrate that this is a programming question by adding your code in a [mre] that exhibits the problem.   If you don't have any code, it looks like a server configuration problem to me rather than a programming problem.